# How to deal with Symfonys trailing-slash-redirect given the app is accessed using different domains and path prefixes?

Tags: php, symfony, cdn, akamai

We maintain an api with Symfony 5 running on PHP 8 hosted on Heroku.

Every route is prefixed with `/api`, e.g. `/api/myresource`. Symfony router includes a built-in 301 redirect for routes with trailing /. Therefore, a request `GET https://example.herokapp.com/api/myresource/` is answered with a redirect

```
GET https://example.herokapp.com/api/myresource/
HTTP 301
Location: https://example.herokapp.com/api/myresource <-- no trailing slash
```

Our api is accessed through akamai CDN which also acts as a http cache. On akamai the api is configured as backend for `/my-backend-api` e.g.
`https://example.com/my-backend-api/myresource` points to `https://example.herokapp.com/api/myresource`.

That works fine so far, but our problem comes with the trailing slash redirect feature. When we ignore the `X-Forwarded-Host`-Header on the backend api, we get redirects that bypass the CDN:

```
GET https://example.com/my-backend-api/myresource/
HTTP 301
Location: https://example.herokapp.com/api/myresource
```

This breaks our caching.

When we respect `X-Forwarded-Host` its even worse, because

```
GET https://example.com/my-backend-api/myresource/
HTTP 301
Location: https://example.com/api/myresource <-- wrong path prefix
```

Which results in a 404 because the prefix `/my-backend-api` that our cdn expects is missing.

How can we handle that situation?
Is there a simple way to set a route prefix depending on the hostname? Would it be wiser to disable trailing-slash-redirect completely and respond with 404 on trailing slashes or treating them as alias and respond with 200? What would be the best way to do that?